# Reusing data cached from one query in another

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Given a simple graphql schema that looks something like:

```
type Contact {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}

type Query {
    RecentContacts: [Contact]
    Contact(id: ID!): Contact
}
```

If I query Recent contacts:

```
const GET_RECENT_CONTACTS = gql`
    query RecentContacts {
        RecentContacts {
          id
          name
        }
    }`

<Query client={client} query={GET_RECENT_CONTACTS}>
    {({loading, error, data}) => { /* etc... */ }}
</Query>
```

And receive data for e.g. contacts with ids 1 and 2, which is cached like:

```
ROOT_QUERY
    RecentContacts: [Contact]
        0:  Contact:1
              id: 1
              name: Jack
        1:  Contact:2
              id: 2
              name: Jill
```

Is there a way to let Apollo know that it can used the already-cached entries for queries `Contact(id: 1)` and `Contact(id: 2)` without needing to make another network request just to bring back data that already exists in the cache?

Specifically, I would like for this query to not have to make a network request after `RecentContacts` has been queried, since the data it needs is already in the cache (albeit returned from a call to a different query):

```
const GET_CONTACT = gql`
    query Contact($id: ID!){
        Contact(id: $id){
          id
          name
        }
    }

<Query client={client} query={GET_CONTACT} variables={{id: 1}}>
    {({loading, error, data}) => {/* etc... */}}
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cache redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect) to do just that. Here's the example from the docs modified to work with your schema:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      User: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'User', id: args.id })
    },
  },
});
```